# Querying / Retrieving Data from SQL Server using Django

Tags: python, sql-server, django

I am pretty new to Django. I am trying to query data from SQL server using a Django App. I am able to connect with the default Django database and fetch data from there but Django keeps throwing an error when I try to query an existing database. (Apologies for indentation mistakes in formatting here but it is ok in my scripts)

views.py shows the following error:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import Context,Template,RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, render
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.template.context_processors import csrf
from ForecastApp.forms import *
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
#from django.db import connection
import os
import csv
import json
import subprocess
from subprocess import *
from operator import itemgetter
from datetime import datetime
import pyodbc
from logging import getLogger
from .models import Actuals
from .models import forecastfuture
ss = forecastfuture.objects.using('default').all()
    print len(ss)
    for row in ss:
        print (row.region) #works fine
tt = Actuals.objects.using('Forecasting').all()
    print len(tt)
        for row in tt:
            print (row.Region)
```

[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'id'. (207)

I have set up routers.py and models.py and settings.py per instructions in documentation.

routers.py

```
class App1Router(object): #pardon my poor indentations here while posting
def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):

    if model._meta.app_label == 'ForecastApp':
        return 'Forecasting'
    return 'default'

def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):

    if model._meta.app_label == 'ForecastApp':
        return 'Forecasting'
    return 'default'

def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):

    if obj1._meta.app_label == 'ForecastApp' and obj2._meta.app_label == 'ForecastApp':
        return True
    # Allow if neither is chinook app
    elif 'ForecastApp' not in [obj1._meta.app_label, obj2._meta.app_label]:
        return True
    return False

def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
    if db == 'Forecasting' or model._meta.app_label == "ForecastApp":
        return False # we're not using syncdb on our legacy database
    else: # but all other models/databases are fine
        return True
```

models.py

```
class Actuals(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Date', blank=True, null=True)
    values = models.FloatField(db_column='Values', blank=True, null=True)
    region = models.CharField(db_column='Region', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    metric = models.CharField(db_column='Metric', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'actuals'

class migrations(models.Model):
    app =models.CharField(max_length=255)
    name =models.CharField(max_length=255)
    applied = models.DateTimeField()

class forecastfuture(models.Model):
    caseId = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    date = models.DateField(null=False)
    forecast=models.FloatField(null=False)
    metric = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=False)
    region = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=False)
```

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc', 
        'NAME': 'ForecastAppDjango',   
        'USER': '',                    
        'PASSWORD': '',                
        'HOST': 'abc.com\\sql',        
        'PORT': '1433',                
        'OPTIONS': {
                'host_is_server': True,
                'driver' : 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0',
                'trusted_connection':'yes',

        },
    },

    'Forecasting': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc', 
        'NAME': 'Forecasting',         
        'USER': '',                    
        'PASSWORD': '',                
        'HOST': 'abc.com\\sqlt',.
        'PORT': '1433',         
        'OPTIONS': {
                'host_is_server': True,
                'driver' : 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0',
                'trusted_connection':'yes',

        },
    }
}

DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['ForecastApp.routers.App1Router']
```

So far I ve tried to: manage.py makemigrations and migrate commands successfully.

Actuals table is:

```
| Date | Values | Region | Metric|
|2012-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 1000 | Region1 | Demand |
```

manage.py inspectdb --database "Forecasting" was also ok.

Q1: External DB forecasting does not have a primary key. Is this a requirement?
Q2: What am I doing wrong in my views.py or models.py ?

Thank you for your suggestions in advance.

Comment: Yes, having a primary key is a requirement in a Django model.

Comment: I understand that it is a requirement for Django created database (in my case default database). But is it true for querying the external database SQL server? Please confirm. How would you query a database over which you dont have control over ?

Answer (score 0):

Q2 : I think your tables forecastfuture and Actuals has different structure id column is extra in table forecastfuture

Comment: Thanks for responding. forecastfuture is a table out created by django created database (ForecastAppDjango) and Actuals is a table from external db (Forecasting).

Answer (score 0):

I use this for reading from sql server:

```
from django.shortcuts import render    
import pyodbc  
def base(request):  
server = ''    
database = ''    
username = ''
password = ''
conect= pyodbc.connect('DRIVER{SQLServer};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+
username+';PWD='+ password)    
Request_detail=pd.read_sql("""SELECT  FROM """,connect)
return render(request, "base.html")
```